# ggplot2 create time frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, frequency

I am having a hard time to create ggplot2 from my data. I need to create a plot should look like this:
[image]

If you can give some advice about it will be really good for my research. Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

A very small sample of data set (df) is looks like this:

```
tweet_created_at     hashtag_text
2015-05-08 00:07:58  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:07:58  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 00:10:48  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:10:48  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 02:50:03  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 00:10:56  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:10:56  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 02:53:13  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 02:53:13  pinokyokemal
2015-05-08 00:11:03  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:11:03  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 00:11:06  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:11:06  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 02:53:48  bingolunkararibuyumenindevami
2015-05-08 02:53:48  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 00:11:17  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:11:17  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2015-05-08 00:16:21  ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama
2015-05-08 00:16:21  onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
```

I used this script but I didn't figure out to create frequency part:

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=as.POSIXct(tweet_created_at), y=hashtag_text,color=hashtag_text)) +
  geom_line()
```

I know that the value for y axis is not correct but I didn't find the right version for it. It creates something like this:

[image]

PS: There are hundreds hashtags in my data set so I need to choose top 25 hashtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_freqpoly`.
If your `tweet_created_at` variable isn't POSIXct yet, transform it:

```
df$tweet_created_at <-  as.POSIXct(df$tweet_created_at )
```

Then find your most frequent hashtags and create a select variable:

```
#will look for top 2 now, easily expanded to 25
hashtag_table <- sort(table(df$hashtag_text),decreasing=T)
df$select <- as.character(df$hashtag_text) %in% names(hashtag_table)[1:2]
```

Then plot:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df[df$select,], 
aes(x=tweet_created_at,group=hashtag_text, colour=hashtag_text)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=30*60) #as POSIXct, bindwidth in seconds. Now 30 min
```

Results in (with facets because overlapping data)
[image]

Comment: Hi Heroka, thnak you for your help and it works for me.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer satisfies you, could you consider marking the question answered? This keeps others from attempting to answer the same question. You can do this by clicking the green tickmark under the votes button.

Comment: The end plot will be based on 30 days so I need to change bandwith into days. I guess that it should be like this: 1440*60. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. 24*60*60 might be more readable/obious what you're doing.